# iOS formatted text

Tags: html, ios, client-server

We are in the process of developing a client-server application where we maintain some content and labels in a database on the server side.
Our data sent over to iOS application with JSON.

Our challenge is how we should handle formatted text.
On the server side, you can create text, for example. Bold, bullet points, etc..

Today we save in HTML format - but have trouble getting it to look nice in our iOS application.

Is there a better way to handle this?
What is best practice on the topic?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your HTML by creating an NSAttributedString:

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:yourData options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Displaying the html in a UIWebView should be the same as viewing in a browser on your PC, except for the screen size.